# How to "rotate" a polar equation?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Take a simple polar equation like `r = θ/2` that graphs out to:

[image]

But, how would I achieve a rotation of the light-grey plot in this image (roughly 135 degrees)? Is there a way to easily shift the plot?

[image]

Comment: $r=(\theta-\frac{3\pi}{4})/2$

Comment: Rotation about the origin is simple in polar coordinates, just like translation to the right (or up, or both) is simple in the usual rectangular coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put $\theta-135^\circ$ in place of $\theta$.  Or if you're working in radians, then the equivalent in radians.

Comment: Ah, I don't know why I didn't think to try that. And thanks for the helpful note about radians, I was (apparently) working in radians and would have been stumped by trying degrees.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FatTrifolium.svg

Answer (score 0):

A way  to think about this is is that you want to shift all $\theta$ to $\theta'=\theta +\delta$, where $\delta$ is the amount by which you want to rotate. This question has a significance if you want to rotate some equation which is a function of theta. In the case $r=\theta$ that becomes $r=\theta+\delta$.

Of course if our independent variable in our polar equation was a non-identity function of $\theta$ you might be able to use the [angle-sum indentities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to help you out:

$$
\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta \\
\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta
$$

In case an anyone is trying to programme this in a Cartesian setting like I was trying to do (for a music visualizer) where I wanted my spiral's rotation to be a function of time. $r = \theta(t)$. Normally where solving $r=\theta$ or $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=tan(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)})=tan(\frac{y}{x})$ you can substitute as follows.

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}= tan(\frac{\sin(\theta+t)}{\cos(\theta+t)}) = tan(\frac{\sin\theta \cos t+\cos \theta \sin t}{\cos \theta \cos t - \sin \theta \sin t})
 = tan(\frac{y \cos t +x\sin t }{x\cos t - y \sin t})
$$  /