# Rotations of Non-Conic Sections

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that it is possible to rotate conic sections a certain number of degrees. How do you rotate other equations in general, such as $y = \sin^2 \theta$ or $x = y^3$? Thanks!

Edit: One thing I forgot to ask previously was how do you tell if an equation, when rotated a certain number of degrees, will be a function after rotation?

Comment: `Is it possible` In what sense "*possible*"? It is of course possible to rotate *anything* by *any* angle (degrees or not), so the question doesn't make much sense at face value as written now.

Comment: Ok. I edited it to make it more specific

Comment: How do you rotate the "*conic sections*", and where does the same fail when applied to non-conics?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the curves within the plane about some point in the plane, or do you want to rotate them about a line in the plane so that the curve traces out a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @John Wayland Bales I wanted to rotate curves within a plane about some point.

Comment: Your first "equation" is an expression, not an equation. Do you mean the equation $y=\sin^2\theta$? And by "rotating an equation" do you mean deriving a new equation whose graph is the rotation of the graph of the original equation? (I don't mean to be pedantic, but precision is important in questions like these.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes that is what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: This explains how to rotate about the origin: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you