# Finding the formula of a graph in Cartesian coordinate system when we rotate the coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a graph of polynomal P(x) in Cartesian coordinate system (The Black diagram in picture) which is finite(starts at x0 and ends in x1, just like the picture).
Now we rotate the coordinate system in a way that the points x0 and x1 have the same height (the red diagram in the picture).
What is the new formula of the current graph in New coordinate system?
Is there any function like R(P(x)) to solve this task for graphs that have a starting point and end point?
The image link: https://pasteboard.co/HD1yaej.jpg

Comment: This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function

Comment: Yeah. Actually only thing I should do is finding the angle to rotate. Thanks.