# Practical Application to Rotating Functions/Relations

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations, transformation

I am wondering if anyone knows any practical applications as to why we would want to rotate a function (or relation) in the Euclid plane. I saw this post right here [Is there a way to rotate the graph of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function) and while I found it very interesting it lead to wonder whether there is anywhere (in another branch of mathematics or the real world) that this type of transformation actually proves to be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking whether computer graphics is useful? If so, then look everywhere around you.

Comment: @RobArthan kindaof?? While I definetely do see the practically of that (in vector, svg, art) would you be in a sense assuming that all computer graphics are expressed as vector/relation? Could you please elaborate more.